# Extend splash screen loading time

Tags: flutter

I have a splash screen when loading my app. I implemented an auto-login system in my app, I've tried to re-create splash screen using `Container`. But whenever the splash screen finishes loading, I can see the container blink because it switches to the `Container` from Splash screen and it doesn't look nice at all. Are there any ways I could "extend" splash screen loading instead of using re-created container for it?

I am using this package for splash screen https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

main.dart

```dart
  home: FutureBuilder(
              future: _autoLogin,
              builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                 //Recreated splash screen
                  return Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 213.0,
                      height: 121.0,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage("assets/images/splash.png"),
                              fit: BoxFit.contain)),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data == true) {
                    return const HomePage();
                  }
                }
                return Onboarding();
              }),
```

Comment: Have you experimented with using transitions, to make the experience smoother? Instead of swapping widgets, you would push a new route with a `Transition` that would be a lot smoother.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to perform your 'auto login' procedure in the `main` method before calling `runApp` function. That way the Splash screen will be presented until you call the function.

**Note**: it is good to have some timeout logic, that way the user won't think the app hangs when opened if the auto-login takes more time than expected.